# Gravity sensor value increases

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-sensors

Gravity sensor values increases after each call of `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` the values of event. Values increases and after a little bit of time (about 1 min) reaches a NaN value. Could someone say why this is happening?
Code:

```
private void recordData(SensorEvent e) {
    String label;
    int currentSensorId = -1;
    switch (e.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        currentSensorId = 0;
        label = LOG_LABEL_ACCELEROMETER;
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
        label = LOG_LABEL_GYROSCOPER;
        currentSensorId = 1;
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY:
        label = LOG_LABEL_GRAVITY;
        currentSensorId = 2;
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR:
        label = LOG_LABEL_ROTATION_VECTOR;
        currentSensorId = 3;
        break;
    default:
        label = "UNKNOWN SENSOR TYPE!";
        break;
    }
    if (currentSensorId == -1)
        return;

    // Force set events frequency to value from config,
    // cause sensor events minimal frequency = 0.2 sec.
    timePassed[currentSensorId] = System.currentTimeMillis()
            - lastSensorEventTime[currentSensorId];
    if (timePassed[currentSensorId] < Config.SENSOR_DELAY_MILLISEC) {
        return;
    } else {
        lastSensorEventTime[currentSensorId] = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    if (this.pauseRecordingData || checkSDCardMemory())
        return;
    fileWriter.writeEvent(label, System.currentTimeMillis(), e.values);
}

public void writeEvent(String eventSource, long timestamp, float[] values) {
        Log.d(TAG, "writeEvent(); eventSource = " + eventSource);       


    if ( !this.fileExists ) createNewFile();        
    try {       
        String valuesString = eventSource + "\t" + String.format( "%d\t", timestamp);

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            valuesString += String.format( "%f\t",values[i]);
            Log.d(TAG, "writeEvent(); values[" + i + "] = " + values[i]);
    }           
        buffWriter.append(valuesString + "\n");
    } catch (IOException e1) {              
          e1.printStackTrace();
          Log.d(TAG,"RECORDING EVENT TO FILE FAILED!");
    }               
}
```

Comment: Can you upload some small code sample? Have you tried on more than one device? When is the value reset?

Comment: can you post the code where you use the event.values element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. The most probable one: You have an error in your code, for example, you are never resetting the variable or making addition to the values (for details, please read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html).
2. Your gravity sensor is broken (to check that, try on another device).

For more help, please post your code, how are you accessing and managing the values read from the gravity sensor.

EDIT:

As I mentioned, there war an error in your code. The sensor read delay should be set to one of the possible options:

```
int     SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST     get sensor data as fast as possible
int     SENSOR_DELAY_GAME        rate suitable for games
int     SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL      rate (default) suitable for screen orientation changes
int     SENSOR_DELAY_UI          rate suitable for the user interface
```

And not to a custom value !!!

Thank you for finding the solution.

Comment: It seems, when the device is going to the sleep mode (locked) than values begin to increase.

Comment: But how are you collecting those values? Your application runs in the background?

Comment: Ok, how are you storing the collected date? In the database ?

Comment: Try to initialize your variable before affecting the readed value.

Comment: this is the code befor using values, but the effect is the same.                                                          public synchronized void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: " + event.sensor.getName());
  float x = event.values[0];
  float y = event.values[1];
  float z = event.values[2];
  Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged; \nx = " + x
    +"\n y = " + y + "\n z = " + z);
  recordData(event);
 }

Comment: Thank you, as a good practice, try to declare your float x,y and z outside of the function. This will avoid the creation of new variable each time. Then, what if you try to do x=0; y=0; and z=0; before each =value ?

Comment: Effect the same. I run the service by button press in the Activity. After I close Activity values start to increase. LOG:  10-09 16:03:37.931: D/MEMS SERVICE(10451): onSensorChanged: Gravity Sensor
10-09 16:03:37.931: D/MEMS SERVICE(10451): onSensorChanged; 
10-09 16:03:37.931: D/MEMS SERVICE(10451): x = 4.0902716E20
10-09 16:03:37.931: D/MEMS SERVICE(10451):  y = -3.0440448E19
10-09 16:03:37.931: D/MEMS SERVICE(10451):  z = 1.1290582E21

Comment: Are you creating correctly your service? The result is realy strange. Which version of android are you using? There were some issues with the old android versions (see: https://sites.google.com/a/bug-br.org.br/android/technical-documents/sensors-and-standby-mode) but it is fixed now...

Comment: Try once, instead of doing Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged; \nx = " + x +"\n y = " + y + "\n z = " + z);, try: Log.d(TAG, x);

Comment: Android OS 2.3.5. Before Activity closes: 10-09 16:22:33.209: D/MEMS SERVICE(11045): onSensorChanged: Gravity Sensor
10-09 16:22:33.209: D/MEMS SERVICE(11045): -0.565706    After Activity closes:  10-09 16:25:09.261: D/MEMS SERVICE(11045): onSensorChanged: Gravity Sensor
10-09 16:25:09.261: D/MEMS SERVICE(11045): -3.9276515E11

Comment: Realy strange. There is no issue actually about that. Try to check more in details yourr code. You are probably doing something wrong. I am sorry, I can't help you about that for the moment.

Comment: At the end: 10-09 16:28:33.781: D/MEMS SERVICE(11045): onSensorChanged: Gravity Sensor
10-09 16:28:33.781: D/MEMS SERVICE(11045): -Infinity

Comment: 10-09 16:28:35.823: D/MEMS SERVICE(11045): onSensorChanged: Gravity Sensor
10-09 16:28:35.823: D/MEMS SERVICE(11045): NaN

Comment: The problem was that I use custom value for delay in mSensorManager.registerListener(this,     mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY),
     500000);

Comment: Hi, hm, but why is this increasing the value returned by the sensor?

Comment: Maybe it's not working. Need to use constants SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI or others.

Comment: Oh, yes, you need to use one of those delays: SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI. Good tat you found the solution yourself. If ok, please, add a new answer or I can edit my with giving more precision.